# Cannot access devices on other subnet

Tags: networking, router, ip, subnet

I have searched for solution, tried many, but failed.
I need your help.

This is my network:

[image]

I have simple network with two subnets : 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.5.0/24
Each one is using the same physical layer - LTE router-switch-switch.
Main network (Router/PC/Laptop/Server) is using 192.168.2.0/24 & DHCP.
Surveillance devices (NVR/IP Cams) uses statics from 192.168.5.0/24.

LTE Router (ASUS) won't allow me to setup VLAN, so I tried to use SERVER to route between networks.

SERVER has one interface, eth0 aliased 192.168.2.24 & 192.168.5.2.

From SERVER's terminal I can ping both networks, but PC & Laptop cannot access 192.168.5.x devices. I enabled net.ipv4.forwarding=1.

On Router  (acting as default gateway for .2.0/24 net) I have defined static route 192.168.5.0/24 --> SERVER_IP (192.168.2.24), but it didn't helped much.

On addition I'd like to have access from zerotier network (SERVER is running node).

Where to go next?

Comment: Does the NVR only have one physical connection, and the same PoE switch is shared between both 2.0/24 and 5.0/24 subnets? What do the cameras and the NVR have configured as their "default gateway"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use one network segment for everything? If not possible to change the IPs, perhaps you could have a network segment of `192.168.x.x` using a netmask of `255.255.0.0`.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I inherited infrastructure, I don't have user/pass to IP cameras - I have to cope with it as it is. Single network segment x.x/16 won't work with ASUS router - I've tried, but It cannot manage it. 
PoE switch is chained with other switch and router - they share both subnets, no other devices in-between. Don't know what IP Cams default gateway is set to (cannot access their config). NVR doesn't require internet connection, and thus its gateway is not set.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the hidden part which is not addressed in your post - and which is likely part of the problem is  is what is the default gateway for the cameras?

The 192.168.5.2 IP address interface on SERVER  needs to be changed to the gateway address (or this needs to added as another address).  This could, of-course, be anything in the 192.168.5.x range, but its most likely X is 1 or 254, so if you need to guess, try those.

Alternatively - get a computer running some software that can sniff traffic (I'd use a Linux box and tcpdump for this), configure it on 192.168.5.1 and start sniffing for traffic -  and then plug in a camera directly to it and power cycle the camera.  With some luck you will see ARP traffic from the camera asking for the MAC address associated with the default gateway (this is not guaranteed, of-course - but reasonably likely)

Comment: As far as I can see - there is no hidden part. I don't know what default gateway is set for cameras - don't have credentials to log in, unfortunately. If I had I would fuse it into single network segment on .2.0/24 - problem would be solved.
Also, cameras are powered via PoE. But I'll try to sniff directly on PoE switch with Wireshark...

Comment: The hidden part is the default gateway.  Unless you reprogram your cameras or have a device that acts as a router answering on the default gateway, or do some hackery with NAT on SERVER so it maps 192.168.2 addresses to 192.168.5.x addresses or similar you won't solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah, but there is no need to NAT here... just to route two subnets between on SERVER (that acts as router despite having only one physical connection - on eth0)

Comment: Correct... but which woll omly work if SERVER is answering on the default gateway - which is what Im trying to communicate. (otherwise the packets from the cameras cant find a way out if their subnet)

Comment: ok, i’m understand, but does it really matter if I’m initiating connections only from .2.0/24 network? Packets coming back from .5.0/24 would hit SERVER interface anyway, because of common physical layer, isn’t it ?

Comment: Yes, it really matters.  Packets coming back may hit SERVER interface but would not be processed by SERVER because they are not recognised by SERVER as being for it to handle (the ethernet packet would not contain the destination MAC address of SERVER).

Comment: Yeah. My fault. Thanks for clarifying this out. I'll try to find out what gateway is set to on these cams.